# Change default path of android.jar during ant build

Tags: android, ant

I want to use a modified android.jar(not inside android-sdk) for a particular project whenever I build project by ant script.

This modified android.jar is placed  inside my project directory.I have found that in default build.xml that is inside `sdk/tools/ant/` one varible that is `"project.target.android.jar"` is being used for the path of `android.jar` so I have tried to override the value of `"project.target.android.jar"` variable inside my ant.properties (that is inside my project directory) and set it to my new path of android.jar but it is not working.
Can anyone help me to change this path??

Answer (score 0):

Solution which worked out for me is :`"project.target.android.jar"` replace this with `"blank"` in android sdk's `build.xml` , add same property in ant.properties as `project.target.android.jar=C://Workspace//AndroidLearning//tools//android.jar`

When variable in android sdk's build.xml is not found then only code will look for this variable in projects ant.properties and set the custom andorid.jar.

But this will only work with build tools 20.
with 21 and above it is not working.